# How to check if a stream is empty at the current moment in time in Rust?

Tags: asynchronous, rust

Suppose I have a type implementing `Stream` (I'm using `async-tungstenite` for context). Everything works (yay!), except my tests (boo! – I suppose that also means that not everything works).

I create a stream:

```rust
let (ws_stream_3, _) = connect_async(ws_addr).await.expect("Failed to connect");
let (mut write_3, mut read_3) = ws_stream_3.split();
```

Later on in the program I'd like to check that this stream has not had any messages sent to it. My first thought was:

```rust
assert!(read_3.next().await.is_none());
```

(it was a *very* brief thought – not for the program though, which runs forever like this - a good sign that no message is being received, but not very helpful for a unit test).

Is there a way to check if there are items in the stream *right now* (rather than waiting for the next one to arrive, which doesn't work because I want to make sure that it doesn't arrive).

I was able to fix this for this case by just using `select!` on that future (and a `sleep` of n seconds), but I think my intuitions are wrong here.

Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can call [`now_or_never`](https://docs.rs/futures/0.3.12/futures/future/trait.FutureExt.html#method.now_or_never) on the `next` element, which will evaluate and consume the future immediately, rather than waiting for a result:

```rust
use futures::FutureExt;

assert!(read_3.next().now_or_never().is_none());
```

Comment: This is sooo much neater than my hacked together solution involving wayyy too many `select!` invocations. Tysm.